# Can I use capture, script and html tag inside Shopify liquid tag code?

Tags: shopify, liquid

CASE 1 - Capture + Render
I want to find out if I can use capture and render together inside liquid tag. For example:

```
{%- liquid
  capture imagefromshema
    render 'get_swatch_textures', item: item
  endcapture 
-%}
```

CASE 2 - Liquid Tag + HTML
I want to find out if I can use liquid tag and echo html tag inside it like below. For example:

```
{% liquid
 for str in blogs_name
  assign word = str | strip | downcase
   unless blog.handle == word
    if blogs[word] != blank
      echo <li><a href="{{ blogs[word].url }}">{{ blogs[word].title }} ({{ blogs[word].articles_count }})</a></li>
    endif
   endunless
 endfor
%}
```

CASE 3 - Liquid Tag + Capture + Render + HTML
I want to find out if I can use capture, render and echo html tag inside a liquid tag like below. For example:

```
{%- liquid
  for i in (1..10)
    assign group_data = 'filtergroup' | append: i
    assign group_key = 'show_' | append: group_data
    assign group_title = 'title_' | append: group_data
    assign tag_lang = ',' | append: settings[group_data] | strip_newlines
    capture value
      render 'get_current_sidebar_filters', key_access: group_key, key_data: group_data
    endcapture
  
    if value != ''
      assign value = value | replace: 'amp;', '' | split: ','
      for d in value
        assign count = count | plus: 1
      if forloop.first
      echo <li>{{ settings[group_title] }}:</li>
  endif
-%}
```

CASE 4 - Liquid Tag + Script
I want to find out if I can use echo to print a script inside a liquid tag like below. For example:

```
{% liquid
if settings != '-' and isAdmin == false
 echo <script type="text/javascript">
  try {
   window.EasyGdprSettings = {{ settings | json }};
  } catch (error) {}
  </script>
 endif
%}
```

Comment: It looks like you have some interesting test cases, but what is your actual question/what's not working as expected?

Comment: It seems rendering the html inside liquid tag is not working

Comment: Are you getting any output at all (or Liquid errors) with your code?  This will be a lot easier to follow your thoughts if you can give an expected result VS actual result for each of your cases :)